# Is retainall() and removeAll() method of Arraylist in java works on the Hash code of Object or the values of object

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I am trying to subtract two Arraylist of Custom Objects but the Hashcode of the objects in arraylist are different.

```
List<QuizObject> list1 = new ArrayList<QuizObject>();
List<QuizObject> list2 = new ArrayList<QuizObject>();

QuizObject obj1 = new QuizObject();
QuizObject obj2 = new QuizObject();
QuizObject obj3 = new QuizObject();
obj1.setName("piyush");
obj2.setName("stuti");
obj3.setName("ayush");

list1.add(obj1);
list1.add(obj2);
list1.add(obj3);

QuizObject obj4 = new QuizObject();
QuizObject obj5 = new QuizObject();
QuizObject obj6 = new QuizObject();

obj4.setName("piyush");
obj5.setName("stuti");
obj6.setName("teri");

list2.add(obj4);
list2.add(obj5);
list2.add(obj6);

list1.removeAll(list2);

Log.d("completezz", "List 1" + list1);
Log.d("completezz", "List 2" + list2);
System.out.println("Set A : " + list1);
System.out.println("Set B : " + list2);
```

Comment: **NOTE** every object has different hash code. Infact if two object have same hashcode they are not equal as their `key` varies

Comment: `retailAll()` and `removeAll()` works on the object which are of same type and contains **similar** value not `hashcode`

Comment: You have to overwrite equals and hashcode of your QuizObject

Comment: @Turo Not for this purpose: only `equals()`.

Comment: @HelloWorld As stated, both those assertions are false. There is a 'not ' missing from the first sentence, and 'are not ' should be 'may not' in the second.

Comment: Its very bad practice to overwrite only equals, breaking the contract between equals() and hashCode()

Comment: @Turo Indeed it is, but it isn't necessary for this problem, which is what the question is about, and contrary to what you stated above.

Answer (score 0):

In your `QuizObject` class, you need to override `equals`(and `hashCode` if you plan to use `HashMap`) methods and write a suitable logic that would compare any two `QuizObject` objects.

Below is just a sample code that would work in Java 1.7 Environment, but there are plenty of other ways to do this.

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class QuizObject {
    private String name;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof QuizObject)) {
            return false;
        }
        QuizObject quizObject= (QuizObject) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, quizObject.name);
    }

    //Override this method only if you plan to use HashMaps
    //an ArrayList does not actually need to use the hashCode() method 
    //since the order of the elements in an ArrayList is determined by the
    //order in which they were inserted
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` does not use the hashCode. It relies on object equality as defined by the `equals()` method. You need to override `equals()` suitably for your object, otherwise object identity is used via `Object.equals()` and `==`.